# how to set meta for dask apply_over_axes call

Tags: python, dask

The following code

```
a = da.random.normal(0, 1., size=(100, 100), chunks=(15, 15))
def cut(x,y):
    try:
        res = np.int8(np.digitize(x[0]+x[1], [.25,.50,.75]))
    except:
        res = np.int8(0)
    return np.int8(res)

res = da.apply_over_axes( cut, a, [1])
da.to_hdf5( '/tmp/cat.h5', {'/cat': res})
```

results in an initial call to cut with aguments `x=[1.], y=0.`, which triggers the except statement in the definition of cut.

Is there a way to set meta directly?

Answer (score 0):

As of version 0.18.2 it looks like no, this is hard-wired.  I recommend raising an issue.